# Explanation of GWT dependencies

Tags: java, gwt, jar, dependencies

GWT 2.5.1 currently ships with the following JARs:

- `validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar`
- `validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar`
- `gwt-dev.jar`
- `gwt-user.jar`
- `gwt-elemental.jar`
- `gwt-codeserver.jar`
- `requestfactory-apt.jar`
- `requestfactory-client.jar`
- `requestfactory-apt-src.jar`
- `requestfactory-client+src.jar`
- `requestfactory-client-src.jar`
- `requestfactory-server.jar`
- `requestfactory-server-src.jar`
- `requestfactory-server+src.jar`
- `gwt-servlet.jar`
- `gwt-servlet-deps.jar`
- `gwt-soyc-vis.jar`
- `gwt-api-checker.jar`

Can some experienced GWT engineer please explain to me:

1. What each of these JARs is used for? Some of these are obvious (`gwt-user.jar`, etc.) but some are not. For instance, what's `requestfactory-apt.jar`? Obviously it has to do with `RequestFactory`, but what is `apt` and is it client, share or server code? etc.; and
2. Which "tier" each JAR belongs on (client, shared, server)?; and
3. Can I *assume* that all the source JARs (`*-src.jar`) are meant to be on the client/shared tier, and thus GWT needs their source to cross-compile into JavaScript?

GWT's ZIP file doesn't seem to contain any documentation that explains these, nor does the GWT API documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `gwt-servlet-deps.jar` are third-party dependencies needed by `gwt-servlet.jar`. These are not directly within `gwt-serlvet.jar` to make it easier to deploy it to Maven Central.
- `requestfactory-apt.jar` is an annotation processor (APT == Annotation Processor Tool), it must be present in your classpath at compile-time (`javac` compile-time, not GWT compile-time) and will generate a bunch of Java classes needed by RequestFactory on server side. It also includes the `ValidationTool` if you prefer running the tool after you compiled your classes. You'll find more info [in the wiki](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation)
- All `-src.jar` contain only source code and are only useful for debugging (to step into the code).
- The `+src.jar` contain both compiled classes and their sources. In other words, `requestfactory-client+src.jar` is the same as `requestfactory-client.jar` + `requestfactory-client-src.jar`
- All `requestfactory-*` JARs contain the *shared* classes.
- `requestfactory-client` is a pure-Java RequestFactory client (no GWT-specific code inside), and be used on a server, a desktop application or an mobile Java application (e.g. Android). That JAR is also "contained" within `gwt-user.jar`.
- `requestfactory-server` contains the `RequestFactoryServlet` and related classes. This JAR is also "contained" within `gwt-user.jar` and `gwt-servlet.jar`. Note that `requestfactory-server` has dependencies on third-party libraries; all of them being packaged within `gwt-serlvet-deps.jar` (if you want/need the details, you'll have to go look at the dependencies in Maven Central, or look at the GWT build script)
- AFAICT, `gwt-soyc-vis` is legacy and useless.
- Finally, `gwt-api-checker` is a tool used to check API compatibility between versions of GWT. There's some documentation [in the wiki](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/GwtJavaApiCompatibilityChecker) but it might be a bit outdated. FYI, this tool is used when GWT itself is built to verify that no unwanted backwards-incompatible changes are introduced.

Comment: Thank you!!! I know this was a tedious question, but I figured it would serve as good documentation for any other newcomers like myself!

Comment: Feel free to propose patches to the documentation!